# Converting string to bool within DataReader with Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

This seems like a very simple question, so hopefully this will be easy.

I have a custom `string` to `bool` map in Automapper that simply converts `"Y"` and `"N"` to `true` and `false`. It doesn't get much simpler:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, bool>().ConvertUsing(str => str.ToUpper() == "Y");
```

This works fine in this primitive example:

```
public class Source
{
    public string IsFoo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Quux { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public bool IsFoo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Quux { get; set; }
}

// ...

Mapper.CreateMap<string, bool>().ConvertUsing(str => str.ToUpper() == "Y");
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

Source s = new Source { IsFoo = "Y", Bar = "Hello World!", Quux = "1" };
Source s2 = new Source { IsFoo = "N", Bar = "Hello Again!", Quux = "2" };
Dest d = Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(s);
Dest d2 = Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(s2);
```

However, let's say instead I want to take the `Source` data from a `DataReader`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, bool>().ConvertUsing(str => str.ToUpper() == "Y");
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Dest>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

DataReader reader = GetSourceData();
List<Dest> mapped = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<Dest>>(reader);
```

For every `Dest` in `mapped`, the `IsFoo` property is `true`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up ditching the `string` to `bool` map and instead creating extension methods for `IMemberConfigurationExpression<IDataReader>`. *Extension methods* plural because I also ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429194/automapper-mapping-ienumerable-to-datareader-issue) where numerical data coming back from the DB didn't match the destination types perfectly, causing inconsistent large numbers. Since the database stuff was out of my control, I had to force the mapper to read it as a certain type. So here's what I ended up with:

```
public static class Mapping
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Dest>()
            .ForMember(s => s.IsFoo, opt => opt.ReadAsBoolean("IsFoo"))
            .ForMember(s => s.Quux, opt => opt.ReadAsNumber("Quux"));

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    public static void ReadAsBoolean(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<IDataReader> opt, string fieldName)
    {
        opt.MapFrom(reader => reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName)).ToUpper() == "Y");
    }

    public static void ReadAsNumber(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<IDataReader> opt, string fieldName)
    {
        opt.MapFrom(reader => reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName)));
    }
}
```

The duplication of the property names as strings goes against my grain, but I suspect someone with more Automapper skills could make that more elegant. For now, this at least works.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `IDataReader` the data is stored as objects and not strings. So I'm assuming `AutoMapper` is evaluating anything that is not null as `true`.

Comment: I suspected this could be part of the issue and tried doing a mapping from `object` to `bool` instead with no luck. I may have just botched that, but I didn't want to create too broad a mapping for booleans anyway—if that's even a valid concern.