# Code Generator for populating a POCO class of table 'OrderHeader' based on ADO.Net SqlReader

Tags: c#, ado.net, poco, sqldatareader

I have a table called 'OrderHeader' in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

While I have found tools to generate the POCO class for this table in an automated manner, I cannot find a tool that will also generate the code to populate this class using SqlDataReader.  This can help me save a lot of my time since I am writing low level ADO.Net code in my current project that uses SqlDataRader  to populate data classes.

**My question is:** Is there any such tool ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several free libraries that do this sort of mapping from SQL query results to POCO as a part of their broader functionality.  [AutoMapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper) for instance can convert your `SqlDataReader` to an appropriate `IList<T>` [without too much difficulty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684276/920669), as can [NHibernate](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate) apparently.

Another option is to use a framework like LinqToSQL or the EntityFramework to encapsulate your data, then build your queries against those.  There are any number of good reasons to use EF or L2S for this, including such (probably) useful things as lazy loading and such.

Or you could learn to use reflection and build your mappings at runtime.  I've used Linq `Expression` objects to do this in the past, but it's a lot of work to get only a little gain.  It's fun to learn though :P

I'd suggest reading [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/a-defense-of-reflection-in-.net/) for more on reflection.  It even has a simple example of using reflection to map an `IDataReader` to any type.  It's not a complete solution since it doesn't handle `DBNull`s or any difference between your POCO and the data returned from the server will throw some exceptions.  Make sure you read the whole article, then go investigate anything that still isn't clear.

If you want to go deeper than that, you can use Linq Expressions to build mapping functions for your types, then compile those expressions to `Func<IDataReader, T>` objects.  *Much* easier than using `System.Reflection.Emit`... although still not *simple*.